# Where is the pycharm deployment pad?

Tags: deployment, pycharm

This question sounds extremely stupid and ridiculous, but I don't remember what I did (not anything evil and complicated, though), and the `'tools'->'deployment'` item can no longer be found in my pycharm, it no longer appears in the menu.

I am using pycharm professional 2018.3 on a Macbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the Remote Host Access plugin.

`File -> Settings -> Plugins`, and then check 'Remote Host Access' in the list at the right.  It looks like this in Pycharm 2017.3.3 Professional Edition:

[image: File -> Settings]

[image: Plugins]

The official JetBrains documentation on the Plugins menu can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-plugins.html).